# Android AdMob banner causes performance loss using cocos2d-x

Tags: android, admob, cocos2d-x

I am using google AdMob in my game (made with cocos2d-x v2.x). Interstitials work fine and the banner ads work as well, but introduce some serious performance hits (resulting in some noticable stutter during gameplay).

I only create the AdView once and only load one ad (both during Activity onCreate), but whenever the Ad is doing something (animating etc.) the framerate drops every few seconds from 60 to 20 fps for a short amount of time.

I tried moving some parts of the ad stuff to a Runnable, but then my game crashes. AdMob wants to work on the UI Thread.

Anyone has any idea on how to fix this problem?

Here's the code initializing the AdView:

```
m_AdView    = new AdView( m_Parent );

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params  = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.alignWithParent = true;

m_AdView.setLayoutParams( params );
m_AdView.setAdUnitId( "ca-app-pub-xxx" );
m_AdView.setAdSize( AdSize.BANNER );

AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
AdRequest request = builder.build();
m_AdView.loadAd( request );
m_AdView.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
m_AdView.setBackgroundColor( Color.BLACK );
```